# Pandas read_csv, reading a csv file with a missing header element

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to import a csv file with pandas.read_csv. The file is as follows:

```
    "COL_A","COL_B","COL_C"
    "ROW1COLA","ROW1COLB","ROW1COLC","ROW1COLD"
    "ROW2COLA","ROW2COLB","ROW2COLC","ROW2COLD"
    "ROW3COLA","ROW3COLB","ROW3COLC","ROW3COLD"
    "ROW4COLA","ROW4COLB","ROW4COLC","ROW4COLD"
    "ROW5COLA","ROW5COLB","ROW5COLC","ROW5COLD"
    "ROW6COLA","ROW6COLB","ROW6COLC","ROW6COLD"
    "ROW7COLA","ROW7COLB","ROW7COLC","ROW7COLD"
```

in a first attempt I ran:

```
    data = pd.read_csv('broken.csv')
```

and I got:

```
                 COL_A     COL_B     COL_C
    ROW1COLA  ROW1COLB  ROW1COLC  ROW1COLD
    ROW2COLA  ROW2COLB  ROW2COLC  ROW2COLD
    ROW3COLA  ROW3COLB  ROW3COLC  ROW3COLD
    ROW4COLA  ROW4COLB  ROW4COLC  ROW4COLD
    ROW5COLA  ROW5COLB  ROW5COLC  ROW5COLD
    ROW6COLA  ROW6COLB  ROW6COLC  ROW6COLD
    ROW7COLA  ROW7COLB  ROW7COLC  ROW7COLD
```

Setting index_col=False

```
    data = pd.read_csv('broken.csv',index_col=False)
```

i got

```
          COL_A     COL_B     COL_C
    0  ROW1COLA  ROW1COLB  ROW1COLC
    1  ROW2COLA  ROW2COLB  ROW2COLC
    2  ROW3COLA  ROW3COLB  ROW3COLC
    3  ROW4COLA  ROW4COLB  ROW4COLC
    4  ROW5COLA  ROW5COLB  ROW5COLC
    5  ROW6COLA  ROW6COLB  ROW6COLC
    6  ROW7COLA  ROW7COLB  ROW7COLC
```

if I add prefix = 'X'

```
    data = pd.read_csv('broken.csv',index_col=False,prefix='X')
```

i get

```
          COL_A     COL_B     COL_C
    0  ROW1COLA  ROW1COLB  ROW1COLC
    1  ROW2COLA  ROW2COLB  ROW2COLC
    2  ROW3COLA  ROW3COLB  ROW3COLC
    3  ROW4COLA  ROW4COLB  ROW4COLC
    4  ROW5COLA  ROW5COLB  ROW5COLC
    5  ROW6COLA  ROW6COLB  ROW6COLC
    6  ROW7COLA  ROW7COLB  ROW7COLC
```

Same with read_table

```
    data = pd.read_table('broken.csv',index_col=True,sep=',')
```

I want to know if there is any way that pandas automatically assigns a header and take values of the missing header column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameters `header=0` which first row set to columns and then is overwritten by parameter `names` to custom column names. Parameter `sep=','` is omited, because it is by default:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u'''"COL_A","COL_B","COL_C"
"ROW1COLA","ROW1COLB","ROW1COLC","ROW1COLD"
"ROW2COLA","ROW2COLB","ROW2COLC","ROW2COLD"
"ROW3COLA","ROW3COLB","ROW3COLC","ROW3COLD"
"ROW4COLA","ROW4COLB","ROW4COLC","ROW4COLD"
"ROW5COLA","ROW5COLB","ROW5COLC","ROW5COLD"
"ROW6COLA","ROW6COLB","ROW6COLC","ROW6COLD"
"ROW7COLA","ROW7COLB","ROW7COLC","ROW7COLD"'''
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), header=0, names=['a','b','c','d'])

print df
          a         b         c         d
0  ROW1COLA  ROW1COLB  ROW1COLC  ROW1COLD
1  ROW2COLA  ROW2COLB  ROW2COLC  ROW2COLD
2  ROW3COLA  ROW3COLB  ROW3COLC  ROW3COLD
3  ROW4COLA  ROW4COLB  ROW4COLC  ROW4COLD
4  ROW5COLA  ROW5COLB  ROW5COLC  ROW5COLD
5  ROW6COLA  ROW6COLB  ROW6COLC  ROW6COLD
6  ROW7COLA  ROW7COLB  ROW7COLC  ROW7COLD
```

More generic solution with parameters `header=None` for no columns names from header with `skiprows=[0]` for skip first row with missing name of last column:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u'''"COL_A","COL_B","COL_C"
"ROW1COLA","ROW1COLB","ROW1COLC","ROW1COLD"
"ROW2COLA","ROW2COLB","ROW2COLC","ROW2COLD"
"ROW3COLA","ROW3COLB","ROW3COLC","ROW3COLD"
"ROW4COLA","ROW4COLB","ROW4COLC","ROW4COLD"
"ROW5COLA","ROW5COLB","ROW5COLC","ROW5COLD"
"ROW6COLA","ROW6COLB","ROW6COLC","ROW6COLD"
"ROW7COLA","ROW7COLB","ROW7COLC","ROW7COLD"'''
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), header=None, skiprows=[0])

print df
          0         1         2         3
0  ROW1COLA  ROW1COLB  ROW1COLC  ROW1COLD
1  ROW2COLA  ROW2COLB  ROW2COLC  ROW2COLD
2  ROW3COLA  ROW3COLB  ROW3COLC  ROW3COLD
3  ROW4COLA  ROW4COLB  ROW4COLC  ROW4COLD
4  ROW5COLA  ROW5COLB  ROW5COLC  ROW5COLD
5  ROW6COLA  ROW6COLB  ROW6COLC  ROW6COLD
6  ROW7COLA  ROW7COLB  ROW7COLC  ROW7COLD
```

Answer (score 3):

First column(s) without names/headers are considered as index column(s).

You should also use `index_col` parameter properly:

```
data = pd.read_table('broken.csv',index_col=[0],sep=',')
```

if your first column contains data instead of index, you can skip first row, specify names for your columns, and instruct `read_csv` that you don't want to read headers:

```
cols = ['col1','col2','col3','col4']
data = pd.read_table('broken.csv',sep=',', skiprows=[0], header=None, names=cols)
```